# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream in WP8

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have seen numerous similar questions and I have really tried all the solutions but none seems to work for me.

This is what I have now:

```
        private readonly object _lock = new object();
        List<DataModel> dataList = new List<DataModel>();

        lock (_lock)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
                            dataList = (List<DataModel>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    }
                }
                catch (IsolatedStorageException e) { e.ToString(); }
            }
        }
```

The error occurs on the line `using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))`.

I deduced from the other solutions that I read that this error mainly occurs when **I want to write to the file while others are reading it** or **execute that code block several times concurrently, I end up locking the file.**"

With the presence of the `lock`, `FileAccess.ReadWrite` and `FileShare.ReadWrite` statements, I'm pretty sure something else is throwing that exception.

My question is what could be throwing the exception (`IsolatedStorageException`) and how do I take care of it?

There is no `InnerException` on this one.

**Edit:** Upon Kookiz suggestion, I'm including this code lines

First, I create my .xml file like this:

```
    public static void createDataXML()
    {
        List<DataModel> dataList = new List<DataModel>();

        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists("Data.xml"))
            { return; }
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile("Data.xml"))
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
                    serializer.Serialize(stream, dataList);
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
        }
    }
```

Later, I populate with this code:

```
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
                    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, dataList);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Isolated storage generic exceptions are the bane of my existence.

Comment: Have you tried without sharing or other various options? Unfortunately Remarks on MSDN doesn't say what they are: [`Some FileStream operations are not supported for isolated storage.`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstorageexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that it's serializing your list and not just the pointer? I would try and do a serialize on it then step through the results of that. It is very likely that it is only serializing a reference to your list so when you deserialize it its messed up.

Comment: I have a working example of this very operation at home. When I get off work in a few hours ill post it if there is no answer

Comment: @bland I was working without sharing and other options before including them later. I wasn't having any success with that either.

Comment: @AMR I'm very sure my list is being serialized and not just the pointer, but I'll check again.

Comment: That may sound dumb but... Are you absolutely sure your "Data.xml" file exists in the isolated storage? You should try calling `IsolatedStorageFile.FileExists` before, just to make sure

Comment: Also, you're just showing the code where you read the file. It gives no guarantee that the code that writes the file doesn't execute concurrently, or correctly closes the stream

Comment: @KooKiz I am absolutely sure my "Data.xml" file exists. I did double check and it does exist.

Comment: @AMR you haven't posted the answer you said you would.

Comment: @NiiLaryea Yeah I know my toddler an I are sick so that goes on the back burner haha Ill post it in a min

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a less conventional way of doing this but it IS a way. I was attempting to do something else and this was the result. Just add in the known type you need and this will work

```
[DataContractAttribute]
[KnownType (typeof(List<String>))]
public class SerializableObject
{
   [DataMember]
    public List<String> serFile { get; set; }
}
public static Object GetFile(String FileName)
{
    try
    {
      if (!IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().FileExists(FileName))
       {
         throw new System.ArgumentException("File Doesn't Exist In Isoloated Storage");
       }
    }
    catch { return null;  }

    Object ret = new Object();
    try
    {
      IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

      IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
      IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(@"\" + FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);


      SerializableObject serList = new SerializableObject();
      DataContractSerializer dsc = new DataContractSerializer(serList.GetType());
      ret = ((SerializableObject)dsc.ReadObject(fileStream)).serFile;
    }
    catch (Exception error) { throw new System.ArgumentException(error.Message); }
    return ret;
}
```

The implied task here is that you need to serialize it within a SerializableObject instance. Let me know if you need that code also

### Edit

As promised, the savefile function

```
  public static void SaveFile(String FileName, List<String> File)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileName.Length < 1)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("File Name Must Not Be Empty");
            }
            if (IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().AvailableFreeSpace <= 0)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("Isolated Storage Out of Memory - Please free up space.");
            }
            if (IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().FileExists(FileName))
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("File Already Exists - Please choose a unique name.");
            }
            if (File == null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentException("Cannot Save Null Files");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            SerializableObject so = new SerializableObject() { serFile = File };
            DataContractSerializer dsc = new DataContractSerializer(so.GetType());

            IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            StreamWriter writer;

            writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, file));

            dsc.WriteObject(writer.BaseStream, so);
        }
        catch (Exception error) { throw new System.ArgumentException(error.Message); }

    }
```

Enjoy serializing!

Comment: Yeah, let me please have that code as well so I can well understand what's happening here.

Comment: Alright when I get home ill post it. It's pretty similar to the above except it creates the SerializableObject and sets its value. Then serializes it

Answer (score 0):

My dear, though this exception of Operation Not Permitted On IsolatedStorage is mainly due to ReadWrite by another thread, in your case it is because of ONE SIMPLE REASON

FileMode.Open throws exception when the filename DOES NOT EXIST

Try with FileMode.OpenOrCreate and it will work like a charm

```
 List<DataModel> dataList = new List<DataModel>();
         using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
         {

             using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Data.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
             {
                 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DataModel>));
                 dataList = (List<DataModel>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
             }

        }
```